# AIR App Crashing with Adobe Scout

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, adobe-scout

I am trying to profile my mobile game with Adobe Scout. It is based on Starling, AIR 4.0 and currently it is live on Play Store. Since it gives poor performance on iPhone4, I decided to profile using Adobe Scout. I am getting a release build with -advanced-telemetry option and I have set up my .telemetry.cfg on my PC as described [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html). I have installed Adobe Scout app on the device I am testing. I managed to connect my device with the PC having Scout, however, after receiving some data (like 20-30 frames), application crashes on the phone.

What may be the cause of this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have given us absolutely no information to go on here. We need to know more about your setup. Does a blank/Hello World app also crash? How are you connecting; with the Scout app or through a config while compiling? Is this a Flex app? What versions of the AIR (and Flex) SDK are you using? How are you compiling? There's little chance we can help without knowing more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I finished my editing.